# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/constructs/Construct

Tags: java, maven, cdktf

I’m beginner to Terraform CDK. I’ve created simple code in terraform CDK to create an EC2 instance. but here instead of run cdktf deploy in terminal I’m calling is via java processbuilder inside my main method.

Every thing good till now. My Code is compile successful and Jar build. But we I run the jar by command java -jar target/ getting the below error.

```
└─[$] java -jar target/irm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar                                                                                                                       [0:24:43]
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.example.test.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/constructs/Construct
```

Here is the my file structure

[image]

Here is the Main.java

```
package com.example.test;

import com.hashicorp.cdktf.App;
import com.hashicorp.cdktf.TerraformStack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final App app = new App();
        TerraformStack stack = new MainStack(app, "aws_instance");
//        new RemoteBackend(stack, RemoteBackendProps.builder()
//                .hostname("app.terraform.io")
//                .organization("<YOUR_ORG>")
//                .workspaces(new NamedRemoteWorkspace("learn-cdktf"))
//                .build());

        app.synth();

        //calling cdktf deploy
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("/usr/local/bin/cdktf");
        list.add("deploy");

        // create the process
        ProcessBuilder build = new ProcessBuilder(list);

        // starting the process
        Process process = build.start();

        // for reading the output from stream
        BufferedReader stdInput
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the MainStack.java

```
package com.example.test;

import software.constructs.Construct;

import com.hashicorp.cdktf.TerraformStack;
import com.hashicorp.cdktf.TerraformOutput;

import com.hashicorp.cdktf.providers.aws.AwsProvider;
import com.hashicorp.cdktf.providers.aws.ec2.Instance;

public class MainStack extends TerraformStack
{
    public MainStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        super(scope, id);

        AwsProvider.Builder.create(this, "AWS")
                .region("ap-south-1")
                .build();

        Instance instance = Instance.Builder.create(this, "compute")
                .ami("ami-0e18b1d379af4e263")
                .instanceType("t3a.micro")
                .build();

        TerraformOutput.Builder.create(this, "public_ip")
                .value(instance.getPublicIp())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can spot here:

1. The error you are getting hints towards the construct package not being installed in this project. I'd recommend using the "normal" workflow of running your cdktf program by running `cdktf synth` or `cdktf deploy` in the CLI. You can also compile your program (it it's a standard program like we initialize it) by running `mvn -e -q compile`
2. It seems like you are trying to execute deploy from within your cdktf program. This won't work, it will create an infinite loop since this program is being run by the synth operation that is being run before the deploy executes. If you want to start cdktf programmatically it has to be from another program that is independent from you CDKTF application

Comment: Thanks Daniel, You're write it's creating the infinite loop.
Basically Infrastructures provisioning web server and in that I'll expose the APIs, Folks will call that APIs to create the EC2, RDS..... and I want to record the state.
Any workaround for that?

Comment: Yeah, to make this happen you would need one Java application that is a wrapper around the cdktf-cli (we don't have a programmatic API yet, see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/237). You need a second Java application alongside it, could be a plain project, could be a compiled jar with just the CDKTF program (so the TerraformStack, App and the app.synth() call). Your API program can then use the cdktf-cli to run commands against the other program